# How to edit and rewrite a Firestore document using cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 collections in my Firestore, 'students' and 'student_history'.
Every time a document is created or updated in 'students', I want to fetch it using a cloud function, add a field called {"Created At" : "timestamp"} or {"Updated At" : "timestamp"} to the document and write this new document into 'student_history'.

Here are the firebase cloud functions that I have managed to write for the same :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore.
    document("students/{student_id}").onCreate(
        async (snap, context) => {
          const values = snap.data(); //line 8
          console.log(values);
          console.log(typeof values);
          await db.collection("student_history").add(values);
        });
exports.onUserUpdate = functions.firestore.
    document("students/{student_id}").onUpdate(
        async (snap, context) => {
          const values = snap.after.data();
          console.log(values);
          console.log(typeof values);
          await db.collection("student_history").add(values);
        });
```

Ideally, I want to be able to append a field like {"Created At" : "timestamp"} to 'values' before adding it to 'student_history'. What would be the correct way to achieve this or is there a better/different solution for the entire scenario?
Thank you.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, only ask one question per post, otherwise it will get closed as "needs focus".  If you have two questions, post each one separately and give the appropriate amount of detail required to understand each one on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DougStevenson, although my second question is a follow up for the previous one. I tried implementing the given solution which did not work and got the above error. Hence wanted to clarify that too. Should I get rid of it anyway?

Comment: Your first question is "What would be the correct way to achieve this or is there a better/different solution for the entire scenario?" and your second question has to do with why push isn't a method on values.  They are different issues with different answers.  If this isn't what you intended, maybe you could edit the question to be more clear what your one question is about?

Comment: Hope its okay now @DougStevenson

Comment: It still looks like two questions to me. Would you rather focus on finding a general strategy that meets your needs (the first question) or would you rather get an explanation about why your attempted code generates an error (the second question)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore.
    document("students/{student_id}").onCreate(
        async (snap, context) => {
          const values = snap.data();
          console.log(values);
          console.log(typeof values);
          return db.collection("student_history").add({...values, createdAt:FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
        });
exports.onUserUpdate = functions.firestore.
    document("students/{student_i
d}").onUpdate(
        async (snap, context) => {
          const values = snap.after.data();
          console.log(values);
          console.log(typeof values);
          return db.collection("student_history").update({...values, updatedAt:FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
        });
```

The fix was to use '...' operator.

Credits: tylim